# Trying to convert Hrs:Mins to Mins

Tags: macros, calculations

I am having a bit of trouble trying to convert a time format from Hours:Minutes 
for instance 12:05 into 12*60+5 = 725, ie I would like to use 725 as a number of minutes.
I am already using the number in minutes to set a counter, but when I try to convert a 
string and then set a counter I get errors which dont sem to be related.

I have tried using the following code which works by itself but does not seem to allow me to set the counter.

```
\newcommand\LessonStartTimeMins[1]{\splithour#1!}
\def\splithour#1:#2!{\FPupn\result{60 #1 * #2 +}\FPround\result\result{0}\result }
```

Basically I just want to set a counter from a time format, and I would rather use

```
\begin{lesson}{The Earth (Fri 24/10/2014, 12:05PM)}{12:05}{70}{Earth}{Activities Not displayed}{text Book}{ % Lesson Objectives
```

than

```
\begin{lesson}{The Earth (Fri 24/10/2014, 12:05PM)}{725}{70}{Earth}{Activities Not displayed}{text Book}{ % Lesson Objectives
```

The second parameter sets a counter

```
\NewEnviron{lesson}[7]{%
\setcounter{LessonStartTime}{#2}%
```

When I try to use the hour format I use the following

```
\NewEnviron{lesson}[7]{%
\setcounter{LessonStartTime}{\LessonStartTimeMins{#2}}%
```

The error I am getting is shown below.

```
Runaway argument?
725!\relax \newpage \myLandscapeGeom \begin {landscape} \addtocounter \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \splithour was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.153 \end{singleLesson}
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: It seems that you are using some package. Please post a complete MWE so that anyone can reproduce the error.

Comment: It looks to me like you are supplying `725` rather than `12:05` as the time and this is going wrong. Can you specify what forms of input the conversions should work for: it's possible to build in some checks, _etc._ but we need to know what you'd like. Also, can we assume that the result is always an integer: that can be done easily without needing the `fp` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `fp`, as this is just integer arithmetic.

```
\def\splithour#1:#2!{%
  \setcounter{LessonStartTime}{\numexpr 60*#1+#2\relax}%
}
```

but it's easier doing the operation “directly”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\newcounter{LessonStartTime}

\NewEnviron{lesson}[7]{%
  \setcounter{LessonStartTime}{\expandafter\numexpr\splithour#2!\relax}%
  #1 --- \theLessonStartTime
}

\def\splithour#1:#2!{60*#1+#2}

\begin{document}
\begin{lesson}
  {The Earth (Fri 24/10/2014, 12:05PM)}
  {12:05}
  {70}
  {Earth}
  {Activities Not displayed}
  {text Book}
  {lesson objectives}
\end{lesson}

\begin{lesson}
  {The Moon (Fri 24/10/2014, 16:24PM)}
  {16:24}
  {70}
  {Moon}
  {Activities Not displayed}
  {text Book}
  {lesson objectives}
\end{lesson}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to everyone who posted, this solution worked well for me.

Answer (score 4):

You should perform the conversion calculation first, and then pass `\result` to set the counter. The assignments inside the [`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) calculations are not expandable, causing the problem.

Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newcommand{\LessonStartTimeMins}[1]{\splithour#1!}
\def\splithour#1:#2!{\FPupn\result{60 #1 * #2 +}\FPround\result\result{0}}
\newcounter{LessonStartTime}

\NewEnviron{lesson}[7]{%
  \LessonStartTimeMins{#2}% Stores result in \result
  \setcounter{LessonStartTime}{\result}%
  \result
}
\begin{document}

\LessonStartTimeMins{12:05}\result% 725

\setcounter{LessonStartTime}{725}\theLessonStartTime% 725

\setcounter{LessonStartTime}{\result}\theLessonStartTime% 725

\begin{lesson}
  {The Earth (Fri 24/10/2014, 12:05PM)}
  {12:06}% 726
  {70}
  {Earth}
  {Activities Not displayed}
  {text Book}
  {lesson objectives}
\end{lesson}


\end{document}
```

> 725
>   725
>   725
>   726